# Typedef not working as parameter or return in Arduino sketch function

Tags: c, arduino, typedef

Im trying to do a linked list in the Arduino ide.

Code is as follows:

```
typedef struct ll{  
    struct ll * prev;
    unsigned int currTime;
    unsigned int stopTime;
    struct ll * next;
} TIMING;

 TIMING * head;
 TIMING * current;

void setup();
void add_new_first(int stopTimer, TIMING * head);

void main() {
 init();
 setup();
 // Code that uses the def
 head->prev = NULL;  
 head->next = NULL;
 head->currTime = 0;
 head->stopTime = 200;

}
```

There is also the actual code of the functions at the end.

This example gives me the error :

> service_timer_cpp.cpp:5:34: error: ‘TIMING’ has not been declared.

When not using the defined type as a parameter or return from a function it works without errors.

This is how I thought it could be done in c and has worked for me earlier. I don't understand why it is not working in the Arduino environment.

Comment: but using `ll` instead of `TIMING` works just fine, doesn't it?

Comment: No, I tried that in desperation. I get 'service_timer_cpp.cpp:4:34: error: ‘ll’ has not been declared'

Comment: how 'bout `struct ll`? http://softsolder.com/2009/10/06/arduino-be-careful-with-the-preprocessor/

Comment: @Pavel This worked. Write is as an answer and I'll accept it. I haven't used the Arduino language before and was under the belief that it was actually c/c++

Comment: @Pavel, good article. I have only used Arduino a little bit and didn't know that either.

Comment: @Einar, I wonder if you can do the `typedef` after the struct has been defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [one of our fellow Adruino developers](http://softsolder.com/2009/10/06/arduino-be-careful-with-the-preprocessor/), the preprocessor works differently than for regular C. There's some code generation happening on-the-fly during the compilation, which is explained in detail in http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess:

> **Transformations to the main sketch file**
>
> The Arduino environment performs a few transformations to your main
>   sketch file (the concatenation of all the tabs in the sketch without
>   extensions) before passing it to the avr-gcc compiler. First, #include
>   "Arduino.h", or for versions less than 1.0, #include "WProgram.h" is
>   added to the top of your sketch. This header file (found in
>   /hardware/cores//) includes all the defintions needed
>   for the standard Arduino core.
>
> **Next, the environment searches for function definitions within your main sketch file and creates declarations (prototypes) for them. These
>   are inserted after any comments or pre-processor statements (#includes
>   or #defines), but before any other statements (including type
>   declarations). This means that if you want to use a custom type as a
>   function argument, you should declare it within a separate header
>   file.** Also, this generation isn't perfect: it won't create
>   prototypes for functions that have default argument values, or which
>   are declared within a namespace or class.
>
> Finally, the contents of the current target's main.cxx file are
>   appended to the bottom of your sketch.

This is why `struct ll` works fine as a type (no typedef needed), but typedef'ing leads to a compilation error in the code that you don't see.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an Arduino to play with, but you are not mallocing the needed space for the two TIMING pointers you made. If I add `head = malloc(sizeof(TIMING)); current = malloc(sizeof(TIMING));` to your main (and remove `init()` and `setup()`).

Don't forget about `#includes` as stdlib will be needed for malloc.